# How to rename a spreadsheet from Apps Script Code

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a autoscheduled script runs everyday and creates a sheet for reporting some data daily. Sheet name is the date with yyyy-MM-dd format and I want to update the spreadsheet name with the date when script runs and creates a new sheet. For example my SpreadSheet name is MY_SPREAD_SHEET and once script is executed today then it should be updated as "MY_SPREAD_SHEET 2018-03-20" and similar for coming days. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my questions answer as below:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().rename("Renamed Spreadsheet");
```

my intent was renaming the spreadsheet document not the sheets in it.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 3):

from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#rename(String))

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet("Hello world");
```

Comment: I think OP wants `rename()`, no?

Comment: that's exactly what it does, no ?

Comment: one renames the sheet, and the other the spreadsheet - if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Oh, I just saw, the link from the docs points to the right method, however the method you posted here is for another purpose. Anticipating your edit, you have my +1

Comment: @Adelin, you're right, but the question is somewhat ambiguous, it talks about renaming sheets and spreadsheets... I didn't want to choose ;) The link shows both usages indeed...  and thx for the +1 !